# why public static final string can not used in java switch

Tags: java

java support switch a string, but in the case field, how to use a constant string? 
Like this:

```
PhxLog l = new PhxLog();        
for (String s : l.FIELDS) {
        Object v = mapBaseData.getData().get(s);
            switch (s) {
                case l.LOG_FIELD_TIME:   // this is wrong, but how to use a constant instead of a "xxxx"
                    l.setTime((String)v);
                    break;
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `l`, it's class and the value of `LOG_FIELD_TIME`. If you really want a switch here, why not enum?

Comment: Why isn't your code working exactly? Seems to work here. http://ideone.com/tiS3RA

Comment: I did a quick test.  If `l` is a reference to `ClassOfL`, and `LOG_FIELD_TIME` is defined as `private static final String` in `ClassOfL`, then `case ClassOfL.LOG_FIELD_TIME:..` ought to work.

Comment: We cannot give a correct answer without more information.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Only if it refers to a [*constant variable*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28-110-N).

Comment: yes, enum is OK too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Credit goes to EJP's answer)

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11), it mentioned that expression you put in case needs to be a Constant Expression.

There are different form of Constant Expression, and String contants are in the list:

> Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that
>   refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

From your code, it gives a hint that `l.LOG_FIELD_TIME` does not fulfill the requirement, because `l` is not a `TypeName` (hinted by `for (String s : l) {`).  If `LOG_FIELD_TIME` is really a `static final` field, you should use `ClassNameOfL.LOG_FIELD_TIME` instead, and thing should work.

Comment: To borrow from @cricket_007's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316277/why-public-static-final-string-can-not-used-in-java-switch#comment77595204_45316277): http://ideone.com/DFNu7w

Comment: Thanks. Change l.LOG_FIELD_TIME to PhxLog.LOG_FIELD_TIME, it works.

Comment: Consider accepting answer if it answer your question.

Comment: It is interesting that e.g ITEM from `public static final String ITEM = some_enum.name()` doesn't consider as constant and coudn't be used in switch.

Answer (score -2):

> how to use a constant instead of a "xxxx"

You can't. [JLS 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> Every case label has a case constant, which is either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant.

The name of a `static final String` is not a constant expression.

You could use an `enum`, as it says.

Comment: So we're downvoting the JLS now?

Comment: Just curious here. Does using a static final string differ from, say `case Math.PI`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't see how, given that wording.

Comment: Just curious, isn't `ClassName.FIELD_NAME` a constant expression, given `FIELD_NAME` is declared as `static final`?  From the JLS link you quoted: `Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4). ` is also considered as constant expression

Comment: Where does the JLS say a `static final String` variable can't qualify as a constant expression?